# Socket.io a particular event emit is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have backend in nodejs and frontend in Reactjs, I am using socket.io for live event handling, everything works fine apart from one thing. I am attaching my server and client code snippets here :

server.js

```js
socket.on("joinroom", ({ roomid, username }, callback) => {
  console.log("student joined room", username);
  socket.join(roomid);
  socket.to(roomid).emit("newstudentcount");
  socket.to(roomid).emit("scoreupdate");
  socket.to(roomid).emit("info", { username, roomid });
});
```

and for client react application:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:5000");

  socket.emit("joinroom", {
      username: this.props.userData.username,
      roomid: this.props.roomInfo.roomid,
  });
    
  socket.on("scoreupdate", () => {
    console.log("order to get score")
    this.getMyScore();
  })
        
  socket.on("newpuzzle", ({ config, min, sec }) => {
    console.log("TEACHER GAVE ME NEW PUZZLE");
    console.log(config, min, sec);
    this.setState({
      puzConfig: config,
      time: this.calculateSeconds(min,sec),
        totalTIme: this.calculateSeconds(min,sec),
        isPuzAssign: true,
      });
      this.startTimer();
  });

}
```

every other event emits work fine apart from `scoreupdate` event. Now I am not sure what is wrong here, either the client is unable to read the event or the server is not emitting the event. In either case, I don't see any issue in this code.

Things I have already tried:

1. changing event name
2. changing sequence of events
3. removing other events apart from `scoreupdate`.

Nothing works.
It would be great if someone could help.

Comment: Hi, try to use socket.onAny(eventName, ...args), and check the eventName argument to see if scoreupdate is being called

Comment: Did you log the `roomid` to double-check that the event is emitted to the correct room?

Comment: Yes i logged the `roomid`, it is correct. I have no idea what is going wrong. Also there are a few other places where i am emitting `scoreupdate` but even they dont seem to work.

Comment: @lissettdm i'll give that a try.

Comment: @lissettdm I tried it this way, ```socket.onAny((event, ...args) => {console.log(`got ${event}`);});```. But this does not log any of the events, event the ones which are working fine.

Comment: Try with socket.on('*', (event, data)=> {})

Comment: Already tried that, nothing!